# Autohotkey: Adapting full-screen images from 1080p to 4k display?

Tags: autohotkey

**TL;DR**

An absolute AHK neophyte asks: How do you tweak an AHK script so that a full-screen image can display properly on a 4k monitor (considering the script was originally written for a 1080p resolution)?

Here's the program I'm trying to fix: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbypodhincq6jnm/Install%20God%27s%20Presence?dl=0

---

**Full version of the question:**

Hi! I have a little AHK script that executes a very simple task: it displays an image across the entire screen for 30 seconds every 30 minutes.

It worked well for my old 1080p display, but recently I switched to a 4k one and the image now occupies just a small corner of the screen.

So I wondered if you could help: How can I get the image to display full-screen on my new 4k device?

I have a hunch this should be easy to fix if one just tweaks a few numbers here and there, but that's all I know. I've searched around in the AHK forums, but strangely I can't seem to find an answer for this specific little problem. So I apologize I can't offer more info!

Here's the program I'm trying to fix: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbypodhincq6jnm/Install%20God%27s%20Presence?dl=0

Comment: As best practice, avoid linking executables in your question. However, at least because the compiled script is AHK, I was able to extract the source code. The line `imgH := imgW/object@ar` should be `imgH := imgW/object_AR` and the line `Gui, GOD:Add, Picture, x%imgX% y0 w-1 h%A_ScreenHeight% vImage,  %image_file%` should be `Gui, GOD:Add, Picture, x%imgX% y0 w%imgW% h%imgH% vImage,  %image_file%`. As I do not have a 4K capable display, I cannot test these changes.

Comment: I also see that you are embedding icons in your script. I would suggest making use of the [Compile AHK II](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=16061) tool which allows changing the inbuilt icons of the compiled file which will save you having to FileInstall them to a directory.

Comment: Lastly, instead of looping constantly to check if it's on the hour or half-past, a more efficient way is to set a timer that will fire `DisplayGUI` subroutine at the appropriate time. The first run will need to be delayed. This can be achieved using `SetTimer, FirstDisplayGUI, % (30 - Mod(A_Min, 30)) * -60000`. In the `FirstDisplayGUI` subroutine, call `SetTimer, DisplayGUI, % 1800000` and then `GoSub, DisplayGUI` followed by `Return`. To disable the program, call `SetTimer, FirstDisplayGUI, Off` and `SetTimer, DisplayGUI, Off`. To enable it just call the FirstDisplayGUI line above again.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Will definitely try this out!